# Combine on multiple keys in Pyspark or Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, key-value

Hello All I am new to spark..
I have a RDD of form `(K1,K2,Row(val1)) (K1,K2,Row(val2))` where K1 and K2 together make a `unique key`. I want to combine it on K1 and K2 ..

`(K1,K2,Row(val1,val2))` can anyone suggest a way through I have been searching for this but didn't get anything useful .

thank You

Comment: What operation do you want to do based on those keys?

Answer (score 1):

Map your data to a format `((K1, K2), V)` and use it as any other `PairRDD`:

```
rdd
  .map(lambda ksv: ((ksv[0], ksv[1]), ksv[2]))
  .reduceByKey(...) # Or other method you want to use
```